# Mactex mirror broken

Tags: installing, mactex, macos

just today I got my very first macbook (macbook air M2 base model) with Ventura 13.3. I'm a mathematician so I really need Latex asap on my computers. I was going to download mactex and then texstudio, but got stuck on the first of those steps.

I wanted to download the mactex package from https://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html but when I click "MacTex.pkg" to download the file I get the error message:

[image: Error message]
I also read somewhere that I could try with this command on the terminal:

`curl -IL https://mirror.ctan.org/systems/mac/mactex/mactex-20230314.pkg`

But doing this doesn't work either, as I get the following error in the terminal:

[image: Terminal Image]

Any help is appreciated, I don't know anything about mirrors so I really don't know what to do!

Comment: You can manually select mirror from https://ctan.org/mirrors/mirmon.

Comment: And any of those will download the same file? (sorry I know its probably a very stupid question)

Comment: yes, you can also check the hash of file.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!

Comment: @AnaEmiliadeOrellana if you want, you can post your own answer and then tick it as accepted after 48 hours, helps keep the site clean and so future people know what the issue/solution is `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by [Clara](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/238422/clara), mactex can be downloaded by selecting another mirror here: https://ctan.org/mirrors/mirmon